# Web SharePoint Web Analytics Erroring

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I have configuraed Web analytics on SharePoint Server using the Central Admin. However it errors when I run it on the page from the site settings. I get the following msg:
There is no data available for this report. Here are some possible reasons:

1. Web Analytics has not been enabled long enough to generate data;
2. There is insufficient data to generate this report;
3. Data logging required for this report might not be enabled;
4. Data aggregation might not be enabled at the level required for this report.

Why is that happening?